# What is the exact vectorial analytical expression for the electric field of a laguerre-gauss beam?

Tags: maxwell-equations

When the paraxial approximation for the Laguerre-Gauss beams breaks down?
In such cases, what is the right analytical expression for the electric field of the Laguerre-Gauss beams, for any radial and azimuthal indexes p and l?
I have gone through some papers, but I mostly found contradictory replies.

Thank you very much for your attention.
Best Regards.